# How to multiply two images with different encoding

Tags: c++, node.js, image-processing, blender, sharp

I have two textures map, one albedo and another ambient occlusion. The albedo one is `srgb` encoded `.jpg` whereas the ambient occlusion is `linear` encoded `.jpg`.

**Now, I want to load these two images (preferably in node.js) and multiply their rgb values evenly(0.5 weight) and output the image in .jpg format with sRGB encoding.**

I tried to simply read and write a linear encoded normal map using the `sharp` library(npm, node.js) as a test, with the following code, but the output image looks slightly darker now.

```
import sharp from 'sharp';

const img = sharp('assets/normal.jpg');
const processedImg = img
  .resize(1024)
  .jpeg({ quality: 100 });
processedImg.toFile('assets/__normal.jpg');
```

Even, the metadata() function on the image says the image is in `srgb` space, but I had exported the maps from Quixel Bridge and I know that those are linear encoded, still the metadata returns that they are in `srgb` space.

I can't find any hints from the `sharp.js` documentation on how to force change the input file encodings.

Basically, I want to replicate this operation in blender, but using code in node.js or c++.

[image]

I can use some other library, if recommened.

I am even open to c or c++ solutions if it can't be done in nodejs or gets complicated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: never trust metadata you didn't write yourself. generic image encoding apis *assume* srgb or something like that, if you give them *just* an array of values to encode.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Well I used Quixel Bridge, to download megascans assets, and properly picked linear encoding on all channels (r,g,b) myself. The metadata might be wrong, but I am quite sure (hopefully), that the actual data is linearly encoded.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Any pointers on which library or a combination of some which will help me do the srgb to linear conversion on the albedo and then multiply the resulting images and output them in linear encoded format?

Comment: I can't recommend libraries (would also be off-topic). you just need to find _something_ that can handle gamma maps. if you don't care particularly, just assume that the relation is `linear = mapped^2.2` or 2.4 or whatever. or look up the equations on wikipedia, hope it doesn't lie to you, and implement them. there's a linear piece in the piecewise defined gammas for rec 601 and 709 and the extension to HDR.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz well can certainly do that, thank you for helping. The point of asking this question was to avoid writting numerical conversions on my own and prefer any premade libraries if available, because most of the time they are optimized with machine vector instructions. Ok, then it looks like I have to convert the 8bit srgb uchar to a wider linear encoded type, then multiply, and then figure out some library to write the data into a file by norrowing the type to uchar again. It seems a bit of work to do, but thank you again.

Comment: I was hoping this would be quite a common worflow and there might exist some libraries which might help me with these, even though I know that would be off-topic, but any pointers would certainly help me and any future readers.

Comment: if you're concerned about speed. look-up tables are usually the fastest solution, certainly for 8-bit (256 entries). you just need to populate it, which costs nothing, and then use whatever library to map the image using the LUT. if this were python, I could throw a ton of stuff at you, but it's js... you **could** try **OpenCV.js**. it's an emscripten-transpiled subset of OpenCV. I haven't used the js flavor of it but I know enough of OpenCV in general.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Ok sure, good point on LUTs, and maybe I will have to compromise speed on the multiply pass. Anyways, thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found out a trick with which we can trick sharp to work with `linear` encodings.

So, we know that our file is `linear` encoded. But since it has no `metadata`, `sharp` assumes it to be sRGB encoded. So what can we do? Hmm..

```
sharp(ifile)
    .pipelineColourspace('srgb')
    .toColourspace('srgb')
    .toBuffer();
```

We say to sharp that please while processing our file don't `gamma correct` our `linear` encoded file(i.e. `sharp` would think its `sRGB`, and would have applied `gamma correction`) to `linear` (which it normally does), but instead work with supposedly ``sRGB`(i.e.` linear```) values.

`.pipelineColourspace('srgb')` tells `sharp` to do the `image-processing` with `sRGB` values, and since `sharp` wrongly assumed that our file is `sRGB`, it doesn't gamma correct our file, cause it thinks it already in the required format.

`.toColourspace('srgb')` tells sharp to output the iamge as `srgb` values, now again since to `sharp` our pipeline was `sRGB` it doesnt gamma correct it again, and just simply spits the buffer received from pipeline.

This way we tell sharp to avoid applying gamma correction on our image. Cool.

Now lets answer the whole question, on how to multiply `srgb` albedo, `linear` ao, and output to a `sRGB` image.

```
export const multiplyTexture = async (albedo: Buffer, ao: Buffer) => {
  return sharp(albedo)
    .pipelineColorspace('linear')
    .composite([
      {
        input: await sharp(ao)
          .pipelineColourspace('srgb')
          .toColourspace('srgb')
          .toBuffer(),
        blend: 'multiply',
        gravity: 'center',
      },
    ])
    .toColorspace('srgb')
    .toBuffer();
};
```